# Constant of integration of exponential-type function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The Laurent series about $0$ of $1/{z(e^z-1)}$ is

$$\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}z^{n-2}$$

When we integrate this we have

$$\int\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}dz=-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{\ln{|z|}}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!(n-1)}z^{n-1}+C$$

Something interesting happens when we subtract the expansion from the definite integral form.  It equals a constant.

$$C_0=\int_\infty^x\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}dz-\left(-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln{|x|}}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!(n-1)}x^{n-1}\right)$$

Unfortunately the series is only defined on $0\lt x\lt 2\pi$.

> What is the value of the constant $C_0$?

I thought about seeing if I can do the expansion about some other point $a$, so here's what I did

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}&=\frac{1}{a(z/a)(e^{a(z/a)}-1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}a^{n-2}\left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^{n-2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}a^{n-k-2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{n-2\choose{k}}\left(z-a\right)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\left(z-a\right)^k
\end{align}$$

Where

$$c_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}{n-2\choose{k}}a^{n-k-2}$$

Using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula with $f(x)=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\Gamma(k+1,-x)$ we get

$$c_k=\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{a^{k+1}k!}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Gamma\left(k+1,na\right)$$

So by integration we have

$$\int\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}dz=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_k}{k+1}\left(z-a\right)^{k+1}+C$$

Then

$$\int_\infty^x\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}dz=\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_k}{k+1}\left(x-a\right)^{k+1}$$

Then we can try subtracting the original series expression that is defined on $(0,2\pi)$ from this expression that is defined on $(0,\infty)$ for some $x\in (0,2\pi)$.

Comment: This is an indefinite integral, so there is no unique choice for $C_0$

Comment: Thank you, I was in a rush and didn’t write what I meant.  It is corrected.

Comment: That's not a Taylor series, it's a Laurent series.

Comment: It isn't so surprising that subtracting the indefinite from the definite integral gets you a constant, that is the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_a^x f'(x)dx - \int f'(x)dx = f(x) - f(a) - f(x) + C = C - f(a) = C$. What constant it equals is the value of the antiderivative (with + C = 0) at that $a$. Unfortunately since you've set the value to infinity, the easy solution to this problem (plug in infinity into the antiderivative) won't work because it's not in the domain of the expansion.

Comment: Things seem a little confused here. Aren't you integrating over $z$ in the definite integral to get a function of $x$? If so, then subtracting  a function of $z$ from that function of $x$ certainly won't yield a constant.